# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '80-4' to data type int

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I'm getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '80-4' to data type int.

This is when query fails

```
case 
   when min(isnumeric(CSADR#)) = 1 
     then MIN(cast(CSADR# as int)) 
     else min(CSADR#) 
end as [From]
```

Column in my table

```
[CSADR#] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Updated:

I need to get a range based on that column (it represents number of houses in the same street), minimum and maximum, so I tried to convert that field to a number because I have data like 3, 5, 9, 10, 15, 40 and it is taking 10 as min and 9 as max.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?  It is not clear.

Comment: please see my updated post

Comment: '80-4' is not a number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of a `case` statement is guaranteed.  However, aggregation functions are evaluated *before* the `case` executes.  So, as you have found, what you are doing is not safe.

If you want the minimum numeric value, then:

min(case when isnumeric(CSADR#) = 1 then cast(csADR# as int) end)

However, this still isn't safe because of values such as 2.3.  In SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()` instead:

```
min(try_convert(int, csADR#))
```

Otherwise,

```
min(case when CSADR# not like '%[^0-9]% then cast(csADR# as int) end)
```

This guarantees that all the characters are digits.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation, it helped me a lot to understand what I was doing. min(case when CSADR# not like '%[^0-9]% then cast(csADR# as int) end) worked like a charm.